# initialize a member unique_ptr to empty

Tags: c++11, unique-ptr

In my program, I have a bunch of objects of a custom class Position. The declaration of Position is as follows:

```
class Position {
public:
    Position(int x, int y);
    ~Position();

    Actor *getActor()           { return actor.get(); };
    void setActor(Actor *actor) { actor = std::move(actor); };
    Actor *clearActor()         { return actor.release(); };

    int getX()  { return x; };
    int getY()  { return y; };

private:
    int x, y;
    std::unique_ptr<Actor> actor;
};
```

I also have a class called Actor. Not every Position will have an Actor, and so the majority of the time the unique_ptr "actor" of a Position object should be empty (I'm using unique_ptrs to automatically clean up any Actor associated with a Position at runtime).

The Position constructor is as follows:

```
Position::Position(int x, int y)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    actor.reset(nullptr);
}
```

However, I know that this isn't correctly setting the stored pointer to nullptr because when I try calling actor.get() inside Position::getActor(), I get an error as follows:

**First-chance exception at 0x01096486 in ____.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000008.**

Is there a way to initialize a member unique_ptr to nullptr? I know I could get around this by adding a variable to the Actor class that defines whether or not the Actor is active, setting the unique_ptr to a new inactive Actor, and ignoring all inactive Actors, but I'd rather avoid this if possible.

Thanks!

Edit: I've added the code where I call getActor:

```
bool Grid::addActor(Actor *actor, int x, int y)
{
    Position *destination = at(x, y);

    if (!destination->getActor()) {
        destination->setActor(actor);
        actor->setPosition(x, y);
        actor->setGrid(this);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        inactive_actors.emplace_back(actor);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you dereferencing `getActor()`?

Comment: Do you mean calling it using a Position pointer? Yes. I have a Position *pos, and I'm checking the value of pos->getActor().

Comment: It's 2015, please use [constructor initialization lists, not assignment in the constructor body](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#init-lists).

Comment: @PreacherJayne If `getActor()` returns `nullptr`, that's undefined behavior.

Comment: @PreacherJayne Are you *dereferencing* the `nullptr` returned by `getActor`?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I've added the code where I call getActor().

Comment: @remyabel Undefined in terms of the C++ language, or my program doesn't handle it? If getActor() returns nullptr, I want that if-statement to evaluate as true and carry out the code underneath.

Comment: @PreacherJayne Check my answer. The cause of your error is not in `getActor` but in `setActor`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
void setActor(Actor *actor) { actor = std::move(actor); };
```

You're assigning the result of `std::move` to the **parameter** `actor`. You probably meant to [`reset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/reset/) the member variable `actor` with the parameter `actor`:

```
void setActor(Actor *actor) { this->actor.reset(actor); };
```

---

As a side note, you can simply change your constructor to this:

```
Position::Position(int x, int y)
: x(x), y(y)
{
}
```

This will initialize the members `x` and `y` with the arguments, and default-initialize `std::unique_ptr<Actor> actor` to null.

Comment: I changed setActor to  
`this->actor.reset(actor)`
but still encountered the exception. Also, do I need to change my constructor declaration in the header to match that format as well? I've never worked with initializer lists; I've only been programming in C++ for a couple of months.

Comment: Great! I was just about to mention it.

Comment: @PreacherJayne Constructor initialization lists are part of the definition of the constructor, just as the body, so no need to put them in the constructor declaration.

Comment: I changed my constructor to the initializer list, though I still get the exception when I try to call getActor().

Comment: The exception is not caused by `getActor`. Where does the `actor` in the `addActor` method come from? It should *not* be a pointer to an object managed by another smart pointer.

Comment: I have a Grid object that creates a vector<Position>. In my main function, I have the following code:  

    `Grid board(2, 2);  
    Actor *test = new Actor();  
    if (board.addActor(test, 0, 0)) {  
        std::cout << "actor addition successful" << std::endl;  
    }`

Comment: Then there's an error somewhere else in your code. Do some debugging, and come back (if needed) when you have something (possibly with a new question).

Comment: I found the problem -- I was trying to use return nullptr, and I believe that's undefined.

Comment: @PreacherJayne Returning a `nullptr` is not undefined behavior. If you tried to *dereference* i.e. access the returned `nullptr`, that's undefined behavior.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I was trying to do (and really, why allow the return of a nullptr if you can't use it???). I'm going to need another way to store Actors then. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @PreacherJayne Of course you can *use* it. You are just not allowed to **dereference** it. E.g. `if (!destination->getActor())`, here you're using a `nullptr` whenever `getActor` returns one, to check whether an actor exists in the destination position.

Comment: Does that count as dereferencing it, or is that just normal usage? Sorry if it's a dumb question. I come from a background in mostly Java and C.

Comment: @PreacherJayne If you don't know what dereferencing a pointer means I'd recommend learning the basics of the language before using it (before using pointers anyway). The exactly same concept exists in C as well. And since all object in Java are references the same notion of a null value exists also there. If an object in Java is `null` you are not allowed to "use" it (call any methods on it). The same in C++/C, you are not allowed to *dereference* a null pointer. The only difference is that Java will give a NullPointerException when you do this, while in C++/C there will be undefined behavior.

Comment: It turns out I've been having problems in a different place all along -- I'm creating each Position as part of a vector of unique_ptrs to Positions inside the Grid class, and I think I'm adding the Positions wrong because I'm not able to access any member variables at all. I believe the nullptrs are behaving as I expected, but I might have to open up another question. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to initialize the std::unique pointer to null.  Just leave it as its default empty value in the constructor and only ever reset it to point to a non-null pointer.